# How can I minimize the count of my identical xmls but can still function the way it supposed to be?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

My app has multiple .xmls and their design and functions are the same, the only difference is that I will be inputing different data in each design, which means I'll be having a bunch of tables in my database. My concern is this, since the design and functionality of my xmls are the same is there any way in which I can minimize my xml count but can still store different data in my database?

Here's my main activity so you can imagine how it looks like. In each button there are 10 more buttons that will open specific xmls which I am about to create.

```
package com.whowantstobeanengineer.systemproject;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//BUTTONS START//        

        Button btn_lvl_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lvl_1);

        btn_lvl_1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),level_1_subject_selection.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button btn_lvl_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lvl_2);

        btn_lvl_2.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),level_2_subject_selection.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button btn_lvl_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lvl_3);

        btn_lvl_3.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),level_3_subject_selection.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button btn_lvl_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lvl_4);

        btn_lvl_4.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),level_4_subject_selection.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button btn_lvl_5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lvl_5);

        btn_lvl_5.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),level_5_subject_selection.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

//BUTTONS END//

    }
}
```

Here's the main xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context="com.whowantstobeanengineer.systemproject.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <LinearLayout 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.0"
    android:text="@string/level_menu_text_view"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_lvl_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/level_1_text_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_lvl_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/level_2_text_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_lvl_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/level_3_text_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_lvl_4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/level_4_text_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_lvl_5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/level_5_text_button" />
</LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Under the leve_1_subject_select.xml is this. Can you imagine I have 5 levels(5 identical xmls) plus 10 subjects(10 identical xmls each level) that gives me 50 xmls to manage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <LinearLayout 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.0"
    android:text="@string/level_1_menu_text_view"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lvl1_subj_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/subject_1_text_button" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lvl1_subj_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/subject_2_text_button" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lvl1_subj_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/subject_3_text_button" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lvl1_subj_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/subject_4_text_button" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lvl1_subj_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/subject_5_text_button" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lvl1_subj_6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/subject_6_text_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lvl1_subj_7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/subject_7_text_button" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lvl1_subj_8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/subject_8_text_button" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lvl1_subj_9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/subject_9_text_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lvl1_subj_10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/subject_10_text_button" />

        </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I wish I could only have atleast 1 xml for all levels and 1 xml for all sujects but can still function as I want it to be. One more thing, each of my xml has its own class so minimizing my xml count will also minimize my class count which is good. I don't know if it's possible but I'm glad to hear suggestions from you guys. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look into styles too, they would help reduce the amount of xml contained in each element.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the common parts on both the `XML layouts` and keep that UI part in a separatelayout file and include it in your main layout wherever necessary.

```
<include layout="layout id" />
```

Comment: Meaning to say sir I will be having multiple layouts instead of multiple xmls?

Answer (score 0):

Create new activities that are the same as the first, but with different names. Use the same main_layout.xml file for the activities in the `setContentView` and make sure the code in the activities uses the same button names as found in the xml.

Comment: I'm not sure how the code looks like. Sorry sir I'm a noob.

Comment: In your code that you posted - just reuse the xml when declaring the `setContentView` of each `Activity` in `onCreate`